# Html5 Drag and Drop Mouse Position in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have an HTML5 application which utilizes drag and drop. Essentially the user can drag an image from a "drawer" onto a canvas to create a larger image. I want the elements to drop in the place where they were release. I have this working in all browsers except Firefox.

On the `drop` event, I am using the following to get the coordinates of the mouse, and calculate the position of the dropped image within the canvas.

```
var top = evt.originalEvent.offsetX;
var left = evt.originalEvent.offsetY;
```

The issue is, this property is not available in FF. Is there any other way to get this? Without it, I can't see how to possible drag and move elements within FF.

Note: I am not using the canvas element. I am dropping images to a div. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8523

Comment: The bug is not related to jQuery. I am using the HTML5 APIs for Drag and Drop. Sorry, should have specified.

Comment: This is way more difficult than it should be. Getting the mouse position during an HTML5 drag in Firefox - you'd have thought it would be elementary.

Comment: It's a bug that's been known for 6 years: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521. It is shocking that it's not fixed yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this in firefox..

```
var X = event.layerX - $(event.target).position().left;
var Y = event.layerY - $(event.target).position().top;
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried using `layerX` and `layerY` but mysteriously they were different from same values in Chrome.

Then I realized that **on a Retina display Firefox `setDragImage` won't take the scale into account**.
In other words, calling `setDragImage(div, 10, 10)` would place the cursor at `5px; 5px` point.

Ridiculous, isn't it?

```
var originalEvent = e.originalEvent,
  offsetX = originalEvent.offsetX,
  offsetY = originalEvent.offsetY;

if (_.isUndefined(offsetX) || _.isUndefined(offsetY)) {
  // Firefox doesn't take scale into account so we need to compensate for it
  offsetX = originalEvent.layerX * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
  offsetY = originalEvent.layerY * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
}

originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(el, offsetX, offsetY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Kathirvans answer above but it didnt work for me. The magic potion for my page was...

```
var x = e.originalEvent.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
var y = e.originalEvent.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
```