# Why does Kinetic 3's Text break in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, kineticjs

Kinetic.js 3 is not working in Firefox currently. (See bug [835064](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=835064))
It seems Firefox does [handle mouse events differently than other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435690/html5-drag-and-drop-mouse-position-in-firefox), but I'm not sure if there could be a simple workaround for this dragging problem, or if a web-app must be completely rewritten for Kinetic.js 4.0+ (which does work in Firefox)?

Comment: You can be more specific than this. How about an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: The attachment on the bug report gives an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in Firefox's usage of Cairo in Azure canvas. This apparently always happened in Firefox 18-19 when using Cairo backend, and is [fixed in Firefox 20](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_20_for_developers).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but you may try this.

```
<script src="https://local-py.googlecode.com/svn-history/r7/trunk/js/kinetic-v3.10.1.js"></script>
<script>
/* 3.10.1 */ 
//Kinetic.Stage.prototype._setMousePosition = function(evt) {
//    var mouseX = evt.offsetX || (evt.clientX - this._getContentPosition().left + window.pageXOffset);
//    var mouseY = evt.offsetY || (evt.clientY - this._getContentPosition().top + window.pageYOffset);
//    this.mousePos = {
//        x: mouseX,
//        y: mouseY
//    };
//} 
/* 4.3.1 */
Kinetic.Stage.prototype._setMousePosition = function(evt) {
   var mouseX = evt.clientX - this._getContentPosition().left;
   var mouseY = evt.clientY - this._getContentPosition().top;
   this.mousePos = {
       x: mouseX,
       y: mouseY
   };
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference.