# Getting mouse coordinates in firefox 41

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop, mouse-coordinates

I am trying to drag and drop a element based on mouse coordinates. Its working fine in chrome and IE but not working in firefox.

Below is what I have tried:

```
function createShape(event)
{
    var stageContainer = $(".mainArea");
    var stageOffset = stageContainer.offset();
    clientX = event.clientX;
    clientY = event.clientY;
    offsetX = stageOffset.left;
    offsetY = stageOffset.top;
    x = clientX - offsetX; // works in chrome and IE
    y = clientY - offsetY; // works in chrome and IE

    //Firefox
    var offX = (event.offsetX || event.pageX - $(event.target).offset().left);
    var offY = (event.offsetY || event.pageY - $(event.target).offset().top);
    layerX = event.layerX;
    layerY = event.layerX;
    screenX = event.screenX;
    screenY = event.screenY;
    pageX = event.pageX;
    pageY = event.pageY;
    e = jQuery.event.fix(event);
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

    //Right now this is working but x and y are not exactly correct
    x = screenX + offsetX
    y = screenY + offsetY
```

**Doesn't work in firefox**

```
ClientXY return 0,0
LayerXY return largest number like 173839,173839
pageX and pageY returns 0,0
element.offset().left returns 70 always
element.offset().top returns 63 always

createRect(x, y); // creating element on dragend with x and y coordinates on dragend
```

}

How do I get drag end mouse coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, Firefox does not fill `pageX` and `pageY` properties on `drag` events. The relevant [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521) is open since 2009 and it doesn't look like it is getting fixed anytime soon. The common solution is to [listen for `dragover`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887316/how-do-i-get-clientx-and-clienty-to-work-inside-my-drag-event-handler-on-firef) event on the parent element (although it makes it difficult to detect which element is being dragged) or detect the position of the element being dragged [in some other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435690/html5-drag-and-drop-mouse-position-in-firefox).

Comment: I think the solution which you provided in the links doesn't work in latest Firefox